# Why won't id styles work on <a> tag in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, anchor

I am confused by why my styles here for the id rendered in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari 5. Only when I added an inline style to the element it also worked in Safari. What gives? Here is http://jsfiddle.net/sareL/3/fiddle to the complete code.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#source {
  font: italic 200 0.8em/0.1em georgia, serif;
  float: right;
  color: #89888C;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#source:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
<figure>
  <a id="source" <!-- I had to add this inline style to get it working in Safari--> style="font: italic 200 0.8em/0.1em goergia, serif; float: right; color: #89888C; margin-right: 10px;" href="http://www.cpj.org/" target="_blank">Source: Committee to Protect Journalists</a>
</figure>
```

Comment: Just an aside, but you're using the wrong comment-style (should be `<!-- comment here -->`) for HTML, and you've misspelled your font-name (should be `georgia`).

Comment: What version of safari are you using? Also, JSFiddle your code

Comment: @DavidThomas has probably hit the nail on the head. Correct the spelling to georgia as he said and it will probably start working

Comment: @Jon: the misspelling of the `font-face` is in the `style` attribute, not in the CSS; so I doubt that's the problem, just a typo when copying the HTML to the question, I'd imagine.

Comment: @DavidThomas The typo appeared both in the style tag and the inline css. It looks like the post has since been updated, but i have a copy of the original question and can see the error both times. I have tested the code with correction on safari and can see no issue.

Comment: Alright, here is the fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/sareL/3/ Check it out in Safari 5.1.10 and it doesn't work unless you add the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, support for `<figure>` wasn't added in Safari till version 5.1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure that's it because I'm running Safari 5.1.

Comment: OK, played around with your code a bit, it seems that the `@-webkit-keyframes shadow-shift` rule is breaking the styling. Comment it out and your styling will work. Are you using a preprocessor or vanilla CSS? The // comment won't work in the latter.